# Обработка нажатия кнопки на MaterialToolbar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar

В activity_main.xml следующим образом создаётся MaterialToolbar:

```xml
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:title="Заголовок"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu" />
```

Нужно обрабатывать нажатие кнопки на нём и выполнять код. Я пробовал следующий код:

```kotlin
 val toolbar = findViewById<MaterialToolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
        toolbar.setOnClickListener() {
            // код
        }
```

Однако с этим кодом при нажатии просто ничего не происходит. Если вместо MaterialToolbar использовать обычную кнопку - код работает.

Comment: Это не сработало в моём случае, была ошибка. Однако я нашёл решение.

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось следующим:
MaterialToolbar был заменён на Toolbar следующим образом:

```xml
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:title="Заголовок"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu" />
```

И следующий код для обработки нажатия:

```kotlin
val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
//код
}
```